# My rails form keeps saying password can't be left blank after I try to sign up on my local server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Every time I try to sign up on my rails form, it says password can not be left blank, and I am putting in a password every time.  I've been staring at my code for hours now trying to figure it out, and I can't.

Here is my users/new.html.erb

```
<h1>Sign Up</h1>

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div class="error_messages">
    <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
    <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
</div>
<div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Sign Up" %></div> 
<% end %>
```

Users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thank you for signing up!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.required(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password_digest)
  end
end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
end
```

Thanks for your help, I really am coming here as a last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your user_params method to:

```
def user_params
  params.required(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password)
end
```

Since you are dealing with password field/method I think you should allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Add password to your `parms.require` method

i.e.

```
def user_params
  params.required(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password)
end
```